# Deleted Xubuntu Partition, Windows Will now not boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I deleted the Xubuntu partition, hoping it would just delete Xubuntu and everything would be fine. But now it still boots to grub, and will not boot to windows. I have no idea how boot to Windows, it's not under any of the boot options or devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should repair the master boot record. Insert your windows dvd and follow instractions from http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

Answer (score -1):

Does pressing the F12 key during startup do this (grub), or can it let you select a Windows option/partion?

If not please check the first answer.